# sunburnt - how to see the generated query URL

Tags: python, solr, sunburnt

I'm using [sunburnt](http://opensource.timetric.com/sunburnt/index.html), a python library for talking to Solr. I'm getting some unexpected results and it would help me in debugging if I could see what query was being generated by sunburnt. So instead of doing:

```
result = query.execute()
```

I want to do something like

```
url = query.generate_url()
```

Is anything like this possible? Are there any hacks that can achieve the same effect?

Comment: Can you see the url on the Solr side, via the logs our output from the container that is hosting Solr?

Comment: @PaigeCook: I don't have control of the Solr side in this instance, but I'm sure your suggestion will be useful for others.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the answer by reading the [sunburnt docs](http://opensource.timetric.com/sunburnt/contributing.html#checking-internal-state) more closely. It doesn't get me the exact URL, but is near enough:

```
params_dict = query.params()
```

Answer (score 0):

What about adding a print statement like below (this code is from sunburnt 0.5, I think, but it should be very similar no matter what version you're using)?

```
def select(self, params):
    qs = urllib.urlencode(params)
    url = "%s?%s" % (self.select_url, qs)
    print url #This should spit out the solr url
    r, c = self.request(url)
    if r.status != 200:
        raise SolrError(r, c)
    return c
```